# How to set up access to Azure blob storage from React app (deployed in Azure web app) with credentials from browser?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I got stuck on trying to **access Azure blob storage from React app (thus from browser) with credentials.**
And firstly I want to admit, that I am newbie in Azure, so maybe I misunderstood some basic concepts...

### My current situation and goal:

1. I am developing React app (lets say *MyReactApp*). This app uses some files from Azure blob storage (lets say *MyBlobStorage*) -> it reads, creates and deletes blobs.
2. I started to develop it on my local and for this dev purpose I was connecting to *MyBlobStorage* with SAS - this worked perfectly.
3. *MyReactApp* is browser only, so it does not have any backend.
4. After finishing local development, I deployed it **as Azure web app with SAS**. What have I done:

   - created App service (lets say *MyAppService*)
   - register app in Azure Active Directory and use it as Identity Provider in MyAppService

After this the app works from Azure url perfectly too.

5. But my app on Azure should fulfill 2 conditions:

   - User has to log in with AAD account before access to MyReactApp
   - **App itself must get rid of SAS (because it is not secure as it can be obtained from browser) and use some Azure credentials to connect to Azure blob storage**
6. First condition - user log in:

   - I enabled "easy" logging in *MyAppService* -> Authentication and chose users, who can have access.
   - in Authentication section of app in AAD I set up **Web type** Redirect Uri as /.auth/login/aad/callback

Still everything works great - the user, who is assigned to the app, can log in and work with the app - so far so good, but now the problem comes

7. **Second condition - I wanted to get rid of the SAS to access *MyBlobStorage* and use DefaultAzureCredentials:**

   - I turned on managed identity for MyAppService and add it as Storage Blob Data Contributor for *MyBlobStorage*
   - I obtained *user_impersonation and User.Read Api* permissions for my app
   - I removed SAS and tried to add DefaultAzureCredentials to my code -> but it seems, that they can't be used in browser and only option is InteractiveBrowserCredentails
   - so I tried to use InteractiveBrowserCredentails like this:

```
this.interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential({
            tenantId: "<appTenant>", // got from app registration on AAD
            clientId: "<appClient>", // got from app registration on AAD
            redirectUri: <MyAppServiceURi>/.auth/login/aad/callback // the same as in Azure AAD app,

        });

this.blobSC = new BlobServiceClient(Constants.STORAGE_PATH, this.interactiveBrowserCredential);
```

### My current result:

This shows login popup after getting to the page and after another signing in it results in error:

> AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the
> 'Single-Page Application' client-type.

I googled it of course and according to some answers I *tried to change the Web type of redirect URI to SPA.*

I tried it, but some other error showed up:

> AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for
> cross-origin authorization code redemption.

Surprisingly this should be solved by changing from SPA to Web type...:) So I am trapped...

### My expected result

In ideal world, I want to connect *MyReactApp* to *MyBlobStorage* without popup and with some secret credentials, just to say something like `this.blobSC = new BlobServiceClient(Constants.STORAGE_PATH, credentials);` 
and be able to work with blobs.

Is it possible to **access blob storage from browser** without errors of course and ideally without popup, which needs another log in for user?

### My complementary questions

1. Can I use somehow the logging info from the user (from his "easy" AAD logging)? I can get his info with GET call to /.auth/me, maybe it can be utilized, so I can use his info to access the blobs?
2. The solution should be working on localhost too (I tried to add http://localhost:3000/ to redirect uri, but without success), can it be done?

Thank you all, who read the whole story!

Comment: Why don't you just deploy a simple Node.js server that will act like a middleman between your React client app and Azure blob storage? The server will handle the credentials much more easily than the client app.

Comment: Hi @AntonBahurinsky, you are right, but my current task (from my company) is to create it without backend. But what you mean is, that you would use SAS, which would be saved on server and my react app would ask for it? Or can you be more specific? Maybe I would  persuade someone to use this solution:)

Comment: Just to reiterate you have 2 options, first call your blob storage endpoint from an app running on the server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-storage?tabs=azure-portal%2Cprogramming-language-nodejs and then pass the resource back to your SPA and secure you calls from SPA to app which you are already doing or get resources directly from azure storage, which is what you want and for that here's the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services.